# Should [holiday] be a synonym of [vacation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

In the UK we'd talking about "going on holiday" whereas I understand US usage to be "going on vacation", with talk about a "holiday" being more in line with the UK's "public holiday" concept.

Despite this, should we make [holiday](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holiday) a synonym of [vacation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacation) here on pets.SE?

Comment: "should we make holiday a synonym of vacation here on pets.SE?"  YES.  There is no reason for anyone to post a pet question about a generalized "holiday" (as in a day of celebration or whatever) and need to use a tag for it.  Any other use would equate to "vacation", which is the preferred tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My chat response on this was:

> From a usage perspective, for here, probably. The meanings aren't always the same as, for example, Christmas is a holiday, but not necessarily a vacation. Nevertheless, I think for our purposes the UK usage of holiday as a vacation is probably a reasonable synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I think the synonym would be good to clear up any confusion between going on a holiday/vacation, and holidays such as days of celebration.

The only question I can think of where a holiday tag might be used is if it's something like dealing with a cat and a christmas tree. But the question is about the animal not the holiday so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: A reference to a Christmas tree would be specific to a tree, and in the UK the tag "holiday" would just be confusing in that context as we use words like "Christmas period", "Christmas holiday" or "Christmas break" to refer to that time in general. Or just talk about "over Christmas".